# Pull Up/Pull Down Resistor Confusion

Tags: arduino, resistors, basic, pullup, pulldown

I have googled the crap out of this but I can never find a good answer. In a circuit with a pull up resistor, why is the input pin fed current with a resistor? A pull down resistor circuit doesn't do this? Why not place the resistor after the junction with Vin and input pin?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnmpQI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have you done the math yet?

Comment: Modern logic circuits are have high-impedance inputs, hence they are 'fed' a voltage, not a current.

Comment: What does the 'open' wire connect to in each case?

Answer (score 9):

In your second and third circuits you have the input wired to V+. Even when the switches are closed the input will stay high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7N4Cu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**A** shows a normal pull-up resistor. When the switch is closed the short-circuit pulls the input low, despite the weak pull-up resistor.

**B** shows the incorrect version. The input is connected to V+. It will always win over the resistor and the input will be permanently high.

**C** shows a correctly wired pull-down resistor. In this case the switch pulls up against the weak pull down resistor.

Remember, the purpose of this is to present a clearly defined logic level to the input and not leave the pin floating at an undefined logic level.